# How to exclude specific post_type from default search?

Tags: search

I'm trying to exclude WooCommerce products from default WP search, but I need to keep all other posts types, including CPT and those CPT created in the future. Im trying with:

```
function searchFilter($query) {
    if (!$query->is_admin && $query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'CPT'));
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'searchFilter');
```

In code above I can set in `post_type` what posts types I want to choose. But I would like to exclude only a 'products' post_type. Is there any way to create parameter like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to exclude the "product" post type (= WooCommerce products) from all front-end searches on your site, you can use this code:

```
function my_adjust_post_type_args( $args, $post_type ) {
    if ( 'product' === $post_type ) {
        $args['exclude_from_search'] = true;
    }

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'my_adjust_post_type_args', 10, 2 );
```

It modifies the "exclude_from_search" argument when the "product" post type is registered. See the docs for the [register_post_type() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/) for more information.